# How to Open a Specific Folder in Phone Gallery?

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I have a Application where i use camera

1) In that Application when a user opens a Gallery i am passing an intent to open default phone gallery but i want it to only open a specific folder ??

How i can achieve that

```
Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, PICK_PICTURE_SECOND_IMAGE);
```

2) I want to compress the image which I am selecting from the Gallery ??

```
private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        fname = "Image-" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
//            textview_imagename1.setText(fname);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thank in Advance !!!

Answer (score -2):

```
 public void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
```